# How to use allocatePorts plugin in pipelineJobs in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

Are you able to use the [allocatePorts](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.wrapper.WrapperContext.allocatePorts) plugin in jenkins `pipelineJob`'s, using the jobDsl? If so, what is the correct syntax?

We would like to have jenkins provide a usable port to bind a test server to in a job but it appears that the `wrapper` closure is no longer valid in pipelineJobs per [this deprecation notification](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Migration).

```
No signature of method: javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.jobs.WorkflowJob.wrappers() is applicable for argument types: (PR$_run_closure1$_closure5) values
```

Answer (score 0):

The Port Allocator plugin does currently not support Pipeline jobs. There is a pending pull request, see https://github.com/jenkinsci/port-allocator-plugin/pull/10.